# How to configure Terminal in a Docker container?

Tags: docker, terminal, openfoam

I have a lecture in CFD using OpenFoam. I find it really hard to hae a good time using the default docker terminal scheme. is there a way to configure the terminal to let it look like oh-my-zsh with syntax highlighting etc

[image: Capture form my terminal]

Comment: Probably [SHELL](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#shell) in a Dockerile ?

Comment: How do I change it from the, I guess Linux one used by openFoam to zsh ?

Comment: The OpenFOAM container uses bash to source its own environment and also to provide the interactive shell. You may need to repackage the container for zsh.